# How to delete all information about the old device from the Google account?

Tags: google-play-store, factory-reset, google-account

A few days ago I transferred everything to a new smartphone and **factory reset** the old one.

Even **before the reset**, I signed the device out of the Google account, but it still remembers it and cannot delete information about it.

[image]

This is probably also related to the fact that the Google Play Store still remembers the applications that were installed there and still lists them that way.

[image]

How do I remove all old device information from my Google Account, please?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

> #### How to Remove a Device From Your Google Account
>
> ##### From a Computer
>
> - From your computer browser, navigate to your Google Account dashboard (account.google.com)
> - Select **Security** from the left-hand menu
> - From the **Your devices** section, tap the **Manage devices** option.
> - From the list of devices connected to your Google account shown, tap the three-dotted menu icon at the top corner of the device you want to remove from your Google account.
>   Then select **Sign out** from the options displayed.
>
> ##### From a Smartphone
>
> - Head to your Android Settings menu
> - Scroll down and select **Google**
> - Tap the ‘**Manage your Google Account**‘ button at the top
> - Next, tap the menu icon at the bottom corner, and then select **Security**
> - Then, scroll to the ‘**Your devices**‘ section and tap **Manage devices**
> - Tap the three-dotted menu icon on the device you want to remove
> - Select **Sign out**
> - Google will then display a prompt urging you to confirm sign out. Tap **sign out** to confirm.
>
> Here’s a [quick video](https://youtu.be/xRyRpfOR6EI) we have made on how you can remove a device from your Google Account.

Reference: https://www.dignited.com/80516/how-to-remove-a-device-from-your-google-account/

Comment: Based on the screenshots given on the question, looks like OP has signed out their Google account from their device, but the device is still shown on that page.

Comment: But this is exactly what I did. I **signed out** the device before the factory reset. The thing is, it's still listed there, which I don't want.